# How to convert the input date value of Mui Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, momentjs

```
import * as React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          console.log("newvalue", newValue);
          console.log("newvalue-moment", moment(newValue).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

I am using Mui Datepicker Basic and trying to convert the selected value into YYYY-MM-DD format using moment.js. I have to extract only date and use as payload, But it is not working here and catching the current date.

Comment: looks like you just take whatever datepicker throws at you, you only try conversion in the console.log, just convert and setValue as the converted one not the value from datepicker

Comment: Try with replace onChange line of code with this code  and share the feedback it will help you or not:

`onChange={(newValue) => {  setValue(moment(newValue.toDate()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));  }}`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dayjs` library (small library, `7.2k`) as moment is very costly (`232kb`)

import using `import dayjs from 'dayjs'`

if using Typescript , you can get the type as well

```
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from 'dayjs'
```

use it like `dayjs(selectedDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')`

Answer (score 0):

You can also first convert to date then you can put that value a days()

```
export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

 return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker
       label="Basic example"
       value={dayjs(value)}
       onChange={(newValue) =>{
          var date = new Date(newValue.$d)
          var day = date.getDate() 
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1
        var year = date.getFullYear()
  
         setValue(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
       }}
       renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
  
     </LocalizationProvider>
   );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is when you pass the value of date in onchange of date picker you can have it in a date format and do what you want to do with it:

```
          <DatePicker
          format="YYYY-MM-DD"
          label="From"
          onChange={(newValue) => handleDate(newValue)}
        />
```

and in your **handleDate** :

```
const handleCustomDate = (inputDate) => {
let date = new Date(inputDate)
const formattedDate = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`;
setCurrentDate(formattedDate);}
```